# Java program failing to update PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, psql

I have a Java program that uses prepared batch statements to update a PostgreSQL database.

```
System.out.println(_prepared);
int[] _results = _prepared.executeBatch();
for (int _x : _results) {
    System.out.println(_x);
}
```

The Java documentation for `java.sql.Statement.executeBatch()` states that for the elements in the array returned, "A number greater than or equal to zero -- indicates that the command was processed successfully and is an update count giving the number of rows in the database that were affected by the command's execution".

It was working fine until earlier today. Now, when called on e.g. a single statement batch, it still indicates success with 1 row affected:

```
INSERT INTO participationrewarddatum (anonymized, deviceid, hashcode, id, participation, timestamp) SELECT NULL, '9AE8EE08-0AF1-44B1-8488-E64AA53E4E9C', NULL, 'e1285a4b-6e62-4728-919f-fd9ae7507975', 0.286576152, '2016-6-22 17:24:34.000000 -4:0:0'
1
```

But when I do `SELECT * FROM participationrewarddatum;` from `psql`, it reports an empty table.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple?

Comment: Are you commiting transaction if you are using one?

Comment: And this one `preparedStatement.addBatch()` - http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/

Comment: @csharpfolk committing did it. any idea why it might have worked at first without using `commit()`? thanks a ton!

Comment: My guess is that Autocommit in the connection had been set to true, and someone has changed autocommit to false